# Hey I'm trying to automate something in python using selenium, but I cant seem to click on a button. The screenshot is attached below

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

So the problem I'm facing is that if I try to click the button the chrome web driver automatically closes or if I put it in the try-except block then it doesn't work. Below is the code -

```
try:
    time.sleep(10)
    listen_only = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button")
    if listen_only.get_attribute("aria-label") == "Listen only":
        listen_only.click()
except:
    pass
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5hka.png)

Comment: Is there multiple buttons on the page. Also try printing the error and check what you get.

Comment: Yeah there are two buttons - one for microphone and one for listen only. They both are generated by javascript and they are gone if you click them. I don't know why but I am not able to click them by using any of the methods provided in selenium.

Comment: Is this a personal site or public?  Also your if only checks the first button.

Comment: Public, actually its a video conferencing website for online teaching developed by codetantra for Lovely Professional University.

Answer (score 0):

A simple xpath would be.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Listen only']").click()
```